# How to link a onClick event of a button inside activity_main.xml file of a .Net Xamarin.Android project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I'm developing my first Android App with .Net Xamarin. Doing this, I added a button and now I'm trying to get the `onClick` event of it.

Unfortunately, if I click on the button, I get this exception:

**Java.Lang.IllegalStateException**: 'Could not find method OnClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1''

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:onClick="OnClick" />
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
</application>
```

`MainActivity.cs`:

```
public void OnClick(View view)
{
    ...
}
```

I know it's possible to add an event to the button inside the .cs file, but I'm looking for a solution defining the event inside the `activity_main.xml`.

**Why can my App not find the `OnClick` method and how can I solve this issue?**

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot easily do that, because this requires Java.Interop. Why don't you just go the C# way in Xamarin.Android? I think there is a reason why neither Microsoft nor others offer examples for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `MainActivity.cs`:

```
Using Java.Interop;
        ...

        [Export("OnClick")]
        public void OnClick(View view)
        {
            //...
        }
```

**You must add the reference to the `Java.Interop.dll` and`Mono.Android.Export.dll`.**

[image]

Comment: For more info you can refer to this: [java.interop](https://github.com/xamarin/java.interop).